# Update detached entity only new fields in C# .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

I have a situation where my API can accept objects where inner data can have all the information or only ID. Now If the client sends object A like an example

```
{
"description": "value",
"childA": {
    "id": 123,
    "otherA: {
        "id": 321
    }
},
"childB": {
    "id": 123,
    "otherBNew: {
        "value": "some new text for new record"
    }
}
```

I want my API to detect if "id" is set to ignore other values except for child and if child "id" is set not to look at the value or any other fields. Problem with the context. Update is that it tries to insert Child data with all the values (nulls and defaults) for fields not entered. Also, the child has a "type" which is enum and required but I want it ignored in case id is set.

All child elements are of the same time and the same goes for inner child elements. The structure is simple like so

```
{ id: 123, value: "text", childTag: {id: 4, value: "child", childTag: null} }
```

Is there any way to do this? Or do I have to fetch data from DB each time and only update fields that are changed?

Comment: This really depends on how you are attaching the entity before you save, using `.Attach()` would add it as if no fields have changed, `.Update()` adds it as if all fields have been changed. Without seeing the C# side of the code cant really give best suggestions though

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update only set fields you can certainly achieve that. The easiest approach is to use JsonPatch to apply updates to your entity but as a simple example you would do the following.

```
var entity = new YourClass();
entity.id = update.id;
dbContext.Attatch(entity);
```

Now any fields that change are marked and can be saved in isolation.

```
entity.Description = "xxxx";
```

The issue with this is obviously any fields you want to update you would need to check to see if the value needs updating or not or waste time potentially re-saving the same data. Alternatively if you are able to use JsonPatch then you apply the patch to that temporary entity and then save your context.

For further reading on JsonPatch:

https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/11/29/json-patch-asp-net-core/

Comment: Thanks, I'll check if this can be achieved with json patch. Problem with your solution is that I would not know which data is changed because I'm getting object from client. That said I would still have to somehow know which fields were sent by clients and which contain default values. Example is child tag if it's removed or was never there in the first place it would be null so I would have to fetch record from database and check if it was removed or was never added before. Some of the manual work would be required but I want to minimize it.

Comment: For JsonPatch to work at its best you should implement JsonPatch on the client side so that it compares the old object before the edit to the one they have edited and it would then generate a JsonPatch and send that over to the server so there is no ambiguity. What does your front end comprise of?

Comment: The front end send new Data so no update is possible. Child data is something that frontend has but it could also be edited while adding new parent object by adding child data that does not exist in the database or by editing adding child of a child so it's a bit of mess. Class A contains B which can also contain B. B is present in the database but when saving A you could add new B or edit existing B. I would benefit from mongo by having redundant data (who cares) but it's not my call.